# select multi-column rows based on ranges specified in a separate file

Tags: text-processing, awk, osx

I have two files:

file1

> ST4.03ch10    56000001    56500000
>   ST4.03ch11    34500001    35000000
>   ST4.03ch04    54500001    55000000
>   ST4.03ch12    500001  1000000

file2

> ST4.03ch12    56014301    56019800    0.163   gene    5.5
>   ST4.03ch12    56022401    56025300    0.419   gene    2.9
>   ST4.03ch12    671201  803500  1   gene    5.5
>   ST4.03ch12    671201  803500  1   gene    5.3
>   ST4.03ch12    671201  803500  1   gene    5.0
>   ST4.03ch12    447401  449500  0.038   gene    8.5
>   ST4.03ch12    671201  803500  1   gene    9.5

*edited:added part of my real data here since codes created based on the previous sample data did not work well with real data.*

And I would like to select and print rows in file2 that match one of the rows in file1 under the following three criteria:

```
1. col1 of file2 = col1 of file1;  
2. col2 of file2 >/= col2 of file1, and  
3. col3 of file2 </= col3 of file1
```

What I am trying to do is that: file 1 contains identifiers (ST4.03chXX) in col1 and corresponding range of coordinations in col2 (the starting point) and col3 (the ending point), and I am looking for entries in file 2 that:
1) have identifiers in colA that match the identifier in file 1 and
2) have the starting and ending coordinations (colB and colC) that fall inside the range in file 1 of the respective identifier

expected output:

> ST4.03ch12    671201  803500  1   gene    5.5
>   ST4.03ch12    671201  803500  1   gene    5.3
>   ST4.03ch12    671201  803500  1   gene    5.0
>   ST4.03ch12    671201  803500  1   gene    9.5

The actual files (especially file 2) are pretty big so I am hoping to get the job done using `awk`, but looping if necessary will also be okay.

Comment: sounds like a simple `awk 'seen[$1]++' filename`  or the answer is too complex

Comment: A little bit of additional explanation added and the file/desired output fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{z[$1]?z[$1]=z[$1]"|"$2"|"$3:z[$1]=$2"|"$3;next}
{if ($1 in z){l=split(z[$1], k, "|");
{for (i=1;i<l;i+=2){if ($2>=k[i] && $3<=k[i+1]){print}}}}}' file1 file2
```

This reads `file1`, joins 2nd and 3rd fields with a `|` and saves that into an array `z` (indexed by 1st field) then reads `file2` and checks if 1st field is in `z` - if so it splits `z[1st field]` on `|` into `k[i]` and for each odd value of `i` it prints the line if the 2nd field `>=k[i]` and 3rd field `<=k[i+1]`